# put images in the center of table and text below image should be in new line if extra text is there

Tags: html, css, html-table, center, display

[image: Here is the image]

I want image to be centered of table tag and text to be in new line if it gets overflows.

In table tag, how can I put images in center of table and text below images which are side by side.

I want an image and below it , there should be some text. but when text overflows then remaining text should be in new line.

I can only use **inline css** and can't use other tags like **div**. Also I can't use position property. As I am making HTML Emailers. Have to stick to table tag.

```html
<table style="margin: 0 auto; border: thin green solid;" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
            <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </td>

        <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
            <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </td>

        <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
            <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
            <p>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</p>
        </td>

        <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
            <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
            <p>Some Text</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

as displayed in the code snippet, I want extra text to be displayed in the next line and images to be in the center of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto; border: thin green solid;" width="600">
<tr>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
        <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
    </td>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
        <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
    </td>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
        <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
    </td>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;" align="center">
        <img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455949782.jpeg" width="110" height="110" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0; width: 110px;" align="center">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </td>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0; width: 110px;" align="center">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </td>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0; width: 110px;" align="center">
        <p>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</p>
    </td>
    <td style="margin:0; padding: 0; width: 110px;" align="center">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The important thing is that you assign the table cells with the width of the image in the row above.

Comment: it is there. but it is out of the width of  **td**. so that thing i want to fix. and also when text is overflows then image gets to up whereas text should be go down.

Comment: Okay, understood. But **how** do you want to fix it? Should the cell become wider or should the overflowing text be hidden? I can't really answer the question without knowing what behavior you want to achieve. Please add that.

Comment: overflow text should be down. not hidden.

Comment: i want image in the center of table and text under the image which should be aligned center and if text is more than the width of **td** then extra text should be in next line as aligned to be center

Comment: This is already the case, so I don't really get what the problem is.

Comment: I have updated the question. I want image and text just like in the images. but when i give long text then it is out of  **td ** which i don't want to do. I want extra text to be in next line

Comment: Your text is not out of the table cell (**td**), it is just to long and therefore enlarges the cell.

Please add an image of what you're trying to achieve, maybe I can understand it better with that.

Comment: So your problem is that the images are not on the same height when the text gets split into two lines?

Comment: exactly...  that's what i want to do it.. i want images on the same height and below them , there are some text. but when text are exceed beyond the width then extra text should be in next line.

Comment: I have changed the image.. you can see the in the image. which i supposed to have.

Comment: Fixed it, as far as I understand your question, this should be the solution.

Comment: thank you for your effort.. at some certain , I got the result but still text is out of image width. it should be limited to image width.

Comment: Then you'd need to adjust the width of the **td** further in the inline CSS. 

Please also consider marking my answer as the accepted answer if it solves your problem.